# Do inner workings of Matlab do Full Matrix Multiplication when Matrix Multiplication is Argument for Trace?

Tags: matlab

Does Matlab do a full matrix multiplication when a matrix multiplication is given as an argument to the [trace](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trace.html) function?

For example, in the code below, does A*B actually happen, or are the columns of B dotted with the rows of A, then summed? Or does something else happen?

```
A = [2,2;2,2];
B = eye(2);
f = trace(A*B);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, MATLAB calculates the product, but you can avoid it!

**First, let's see what MATLAB does if you do `f = trace(A*B)`:**

I think the picture from my Performance monitor says it all really. The first bump is when I created a large `A = 2*ones(n)`, the second, very little bump is for the creation of `B = eye(n)`, and the last bump is where `f = trace(A*B)` is calculated.

[image]

**Now, let's see that you get if you do it manually:**

If you do it manually, you can save a lot of memory, and it's **much** faster.

```
tic
n = 6e3;          
A = rand(n);
B = rand(n);

f = trace(A*B);

toc
pause(10)

tic
C(n) = 0;
for ii = 1:n
C(ii) = sum(A(ii,:)*B(:,ii));
end
g = sum(C);

toc

abs(f-g) < 1e-10

Elapsed time is 11.982804 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.540285 seconds.

ans =

     1
```

[image]

**Now, as you asked about in the comments: "Is this still true if you use it in a function where optimization can kick in?"**

This depends on what you mean here, but as a quick example:

Calculating `x = inv(A)*b` can be done in a few different ways. If you do:

```
x = A\b;
```

MATLAB will chose an algorithm that's best suited for your particular matrix/vector. There are many different alternatives here, depending on the structure of the matrix: is it triangular, hermatian, sparse...? Often it's a upper/lower triangulation. I can pretty much guarantee you that you can't write a code *in MATLAB* that can outperform MATLABs builtin functions here.

However, if you calculate the same thing this way:

```
x = inv(A)*b;
```

MATLAB will actually calculate the inverse of `A`, then multiply it by `b`, even though the inverse is not stored in the workspace afterwards. This is much slower, and can also be inaccurate. (In the `A\b` approach, MATLAB will, if necessary create a permutation matrix to ensure numerical stability.

Comment: Suprisingly, `sum(sum(A.'.*B))` is a little slower than the loop approach

Comment: But `sum(sum(A.'.*B))` only calculates the diagonal values, too (+1 BTW)

Comment: @Luis. Hmm, yes, that's a bit strange I guess... hehe, realized it seconds after i posted the original comment :-P